# OnClick Scroll being invoked with wrong current position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a vertical scroll bar with two arrows. One for up, one for down. In order to scroll the user must click one of these arrows. They work well enough as is but I found a small bug. If the user clicks the arrow once, it works great. If the user holds down the arrow, it works great as well. The issue is when the user make multiple consecutive clicks. It is as though the click is happening too fast before the last click event has completely finished. Each element is 60px in height and if it were to work as it should, the last element would be flush on the bottom but after making multiple individual clicks, half of the element at the end will be cut off. It is as though the first click is happening and while in the middle of the scroll animation, the next function is invoking and using the incorrect current position. Is there a way for me to wait for each individual click to complete before allow the next to be invoked? I don't want the button to gray out and disable. Thank you

Comment: If you want you can try, create a fully transparent card, and with the click of the button change the z-index of the card so that it covers the button, and after the animation finishes bring back the card below the button layer. I have implemented this method many times and I have seen this working.